# WKWebView in UIPageViewController unloads on swipe

Tags: ios, wkwebview, uipageviewcontroller

I use `WKWebView` to preview attachments like PDFs of Office-Documents. My `WKWebView` are part of a `UIPageViewController` and everything basically works as it should.

The only problem I see is that when I start dragging my `PageViewController` the currently visible `WKWebView` unloads. And I don't know what is the cause? at least I don't tell to do so...

Did anybody see that problem before? Would be glad for any hint. Also for alternatives. `QLPreview` doesn't work cause it required my attachments to be locally available beforehand.

Here's some code:

```
import WebKit

final class ViewController: UIPageViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let theOneSingleViewController = ContentViewController()
        setViewControllers([theOneSingleViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        // we don't care
    }
}

final class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let bindings = ["webView": webView]
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[webView]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: bindings))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[webView]|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: bindings))

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sample-PDF", ofType: "pdf")!)
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
    }
}
```

Sample code can also be downloaded at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/raspcqpc92fia1t/WebViewTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: You sure, allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures are disabled. Or better put breakpoints  in PageViewController's delegate methods 1:) ViewControllerBefore 2:) ViewControllerAfter & swipe to see if these delegate methods get called. If this doesnot work ,post your code.

Comment: See my updated question for code. `allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures ` didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: So, i found that this issue occurs only in case we load local files using webView.In case a remote URL is loaded it works fine.Fix/workaround put the code let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "pdf")!)
        browser.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)   in viewwillAppear.

Comment: In case your webview occupies the complete screen , u can use -  var browser = WKWebView()
    
    override func loadView() {
        
        self.view = browser
       
    }  , Avoid  adding conraints

Comment: About the constraints.. this is just for demo-purposes... In my real project the view is a bit more complex...
Putting the load request into `viewWillAppear` does not work. Start scrolling sideways and it will disappear and never come back. Also, it would reset the preview to the top. So if you have multiple previews open, it would not maintain scroll-position...

Comment: Mine is working fine - https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZ6tDG7Z5sWXxrvpXfHf82cqlmCLMVmvzOMV

Comment: Yes... because you have multiple pages. As soon as you only have one, the trick with viewWillAppear is not working any more... But I also need it to work in that case :( ... but maybe I'll just try to disable side-scrolling in the one-page scenario... hm...

Comment: Also the reload in viewWillAppear is not ideal, cause you loose scroll-state :(

Comment: you can put a small check in  delegate methods viewControllerBefore/viewControllerAfter that if your next index is  >= pages.count return nil